# How to disable inheritance for Azure pipelines using Rest API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

How to disable the inheritance in Azure pipelines using a Rest API?

[image]

Comment: Hi, I have updated the answer and added details, please check it and kindly share the result here.

Comment: Hi, How about the issue? Does the answer below resolve your question? If yes, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) , so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks. Have a nice day. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The REST API is not documented, however you can track it by tools such as [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or press `F12` in Chrome browser then select Network.

[image]

e.g. I can use below REST API to disable inheritance for Azure pipeline `code test-CI` in below sample:

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{Org name}/_apis/Contribution/HierarchyQuery/project/{Project name}?api-version=6.0-preview
```

Request body:

```
{
  "contributionIds": [
    "ms.vss-admin-web.security-view-update-data-provider"
  ],
  "dataProviderContext": {
    "properties": {
      "changeInheritance": true,
      "permissionSetId": "{permissionSetId }",
      "permissionSetToken": "{project id}/{build definition ID}",
      "inheritPermissions": false,
      "sourcePage": {
        "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{Org name}/{Project name}/_build?definitionId={Build definition ID}",
        "routeId": "ms.vss-build-web.pipeline-details-route",
        "routeValues": {
          "project": "{Project name}",
          "viewname": "details",
          "controller": "ContributedPage",
          "action": "Execute",
          "serviceHost": "{Service account ID} (Org name)"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Note**: If we need to enable inheritance for Azure pipelines, just change the field `inheritPermissions` value to `true`

**Update1**

`permissionSetId` is `namespaceID`, we could get it via below REST API:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{Org name}/_apis/securitynamespaces?api-version=6.0
```

And then search `name": "Build"` to get the `namespaceId`

permissionSetToken is `{project id}/{build definition ID}`, we could get the project id via below REST API:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/projects?api-version=6.0
```

`serviceHost` value is `service account id (Org name)`, we could get it via below REST API:

```
GET https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{Org}/_apis/graph/users?api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

And then search `Project Collection Build Service` in the request body, the `principalName` is the service account id